# Sails.js index.ejs controller logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I'm a little confused on how to add logic to the home page of my Sails.js app. Right now, its just a static page, but I would like to include data on the homepage (index.ejs). I have a MainController and I included a index: function that is pulling in the data. I can't figure out how to configure my route to allow for this.

Comment: Please post your MainController.js file and I'll take a look.  If you want an overview of how sails works check-out http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/.  Look at the archive page for a list of screencasts.

Answer (score 1):

From What you wrote I am guessing you are using Express js and ejs template.

If you are using the Express render method in your mainController to render your index.ejs you can send the data with response like:

```
    res.render('index', { data: 'my data' }, function(err, html){
        // handle callback and error
    });
```

so here you have sent some data

then in your index.ejs file you can get data using ejs tags like:

```
<div><%= data %></div>
```

Tell me more about your mainController method if this is not useful

Comment: I've figured it out. Yes, it is express.js, but sails.js (what I am using) builds on top of express.js to make it more intuitive. I had my index.ejs file in the 'static' folder and it should have been in the 'main' folder because I was calling for it in the mainController. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

The static-folder is for static-content only (as the name is telling us). If you want your website to show content dynamically you need to create a controller like that:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
        res.view(); // sending the view in /views/{controller_name}/index.ejs
        return;
    }
}
```

Cheers!